# "Travel" through Array

Tags: c#, arrays, foreach, enumeration

This is how my array should look:

```
key : value

name : victor
age : 16
country : romania
city : bucharest
language : romania
```

How can I pass trough all it's elements to obtain something like:

```
Console.WriteLine("{0} = {1}", /*keyName*/, /*keyValue*/);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is not an array. That is dictionary.

To iterate over it, use either for loop or foreach loop.

example:

```
        var dictValues = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        // fill dictValues
        foreach(var items in dictValues)
            Console.WriteLine("{0} = {1}", items.Key, items.Value);
```

Comment: I searched more about `foreach` but I didn't found how to get the key name.  Some code would be really helpful, thx!

Answer (score 1):

It should be

```
Dictionary<string, object> dics = new Dictionary<string, object>();

dics.Add("name","victor");
dics.Add("age",16);
dics.Add("country","romania");

foreach(var key in dics.Keys)
{
   Console.WriteLine("{0} = {1}", key, dics[key]);
}
```